# SFMC Soap api request and subscriber filtering

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap, cloud

I have some issues while trying to filter my subscribers dataset. 
First of all, the response properties don't correspond to the request properties:

```
...
<RetrieveRequest>
         <ObjectType>Subscriber</ObjectType>
         <Properties>ID</Properties>
            <Properties>PartnerKey</Properties>
            <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
            <Properties>EmailAddress</Properties>
            <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
            <Properties>UnsubscribedDate</Properties>
            <Properties>Status</Properties>
            <Properties>EmailTypePreference</Properties>
            <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>         
</RetrieveRequest>
...
```

The response I get:

```
...
<RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <OverallStatus>MoreDataAvailable</OverallStatus>
         <RequestID>f09724cb-abb2-4cd7-b3d7-be29a3dbfcbb</RequestID>
         <Results xsi:type="Subscriber">
            <Client>
               <ID>7213480</ID>
            </Client>
            <PartnerKey/>
            <CreatedDate>2015-07-09T10:25:00</CreatedDate>
            <ID>7531894</ID>
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
            <EmailAddress>Abuzzi@bancafideuram.it</EmailAddress>
            <Attributes>
               <Name>First Name</Name>
               <Value/>
            </Attributes>
            <Attributes>
               <Name>Last Name</Name>
               <Value/>
            </Attributes>
            <Attributes>
               <Name>CAP</Name>
               <Value/>
            </Attributes>
            <Attributes>
               <Name>Locale</Name>
               <Value>bg-bg</Value>
            </Attributes>
            <SubscriberKey>Abuzzi@bancafideuram.it</SubscriberKey>
            <Status>Active</Status>
            <EmailTypePreference>HTML</EmailTypePreference>
         </Results>
</RetrieveRequest>
...
```

Would anyone know the reason of it?

Also I'd like to filter by "Locale" property in "Attributes", do anyone know how to do it?
I tried to do it like that:

```
<Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
           <Property>Attributes.Locale</Property>
           <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
           <Value>az-az</Value>
</Filter>
```

But obviously it doesn't work.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you include `ID` as a property, the response returns all Profile Attributes for your Subscribers, in addition to the other properties you requested.

You can't use a SimpleFilterPart to filter by a Profile Attribute. If you need to do this, then you have to create a [FilterDefinition Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_filterdefinition_object.htm).